# How can I get every LI element's innerHTML and display as string?

Tags: javascript, html, string, element

Im trying to get every LI element's content and display every variable as they come in order. I'm using this simple exercise to demonstrate this, since I just wrote it and was sure it would work.

**There are 3 list items**: Mac, PC and Linux. When I want to display this elsewhere, only Linux comes out. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <ul>
        <li>Mac</li>
        <li>PC</li>
        <li>Linux</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    var list = document.querySelectorAll("LI");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        const computers = list[i].innerHTML;
        var all = computers.toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = all;
    }
```

On a final note, how can I set a var for every element gotten? I'm imagining you can do this using FOR, but don't know how to set an independent variable for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You should use `textContent` instead of `innerText`.

**2)** You can create an array and push the data into it.

**3)** Eventually, you will get all `computers` strings in an array. Then you can use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them separated by comma `,`

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll("LI");

const arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  const computers = list[i].textContent;
  arr.push(computers);
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr.join(", ");
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<ul>
  <li>Mac</li>
  <li>PC</li>
  <li>Linux</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code has very minor issue

Try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function showLi(){
            var list = document.querySelectorAll("LI");
            var computers='';
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                computers += list[i].innerHTML;
                var all = computers.toString();
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = all;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
<body onload="showLi();">
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <ul>
        <li>Mac</li>
        <li>PC</li>
        <li>Linux</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) overrides the current node inner html, so like that you will always display the last computer.

Try something like this:

```
var computers = ''; // variable to contain the final string
var list = document.querySelectorAll("LI");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    const computer = list[i].innerHTML; // here you are getting only the li string
    // var all = computers.toString();
    // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = all;
    computers += `${computer}, ${computer}`;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = computers; // outside for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner that gives you a variable `os_list` (look at the console.log when you run it) and sets the `#demo` element.

One-line options like this are not the best for learning, but knowing that you would get many different answers, I thought I'd go for something different. Here is the one-liner:

```
let d=document, os_list = d.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML=[...d.querySelectorAll("li")].map(e=>e.innerText).join(', ');
```

Here is the same thing broken out with comments about how it works:

```
let d=document, 
// this lets us use 'document' in a shortened way
    os_list = d.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML= 
    // our eventual target element whose innerHTML will be populated with our result plus our variable name 'os_list' which will also get the result
     [...d.querySelectorAll("li")] 
     // the [...spread] syntax - this basically says take the HTML collection of <li> elements and make it iterable like an array
     .map(e=>e.innerText) 
     // map lets us take each <li> element and return the inner text. Basically we're swapping the element for the text here
     .join(', '); 
     // all that gave us an array, and join() lets us combine it back into a comma separated string
```

```js
let d=document, os_list = d.querySelector('#demo').innerHTML=[...d.querySelectorAll("li")].map(e=>e.innerText).join(', ');
console.log(os_list)
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Mac</li>
  <li>PC</li>
  <li>Linux</li>
</ul>
<hr>
Result:
<p id="demo"></p>
```